# AngularJS : How to do ng-bind logic check?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have some tweets data coming in, sometimes the database returns a different `JSON` object depending on the server (local, production etc).

Sometimes the tweet content is in `tweets[i].text` and sometimes it's in `tweets[i].highlights.text`

My current markup:

```
<section ng-repeat="t in tweets">
    <div ng-bind-html="t.text">{{t.text}}</div>

    <!-- <div ng-bind-html="t.highlights.text">{{t.highlights.text}}</div> -->
```

Is there a way to check in `ng-bind` if `t.text` exists? And if not then set the model to `t.highlights.text`?

### **ng-if:**

---

Using `ng-if` on the div that renders the actual tweet inside the list:

```
<section ng-repeat="t in tweets" class="social-content">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/{{t.fields.user_name}}/status/{{t.id}}" target="_blank">
        <header>
            <em>+</em>
            <span>@{{t.fields.user_name}}</span>
        </header>
        <div class="body" ng-if="t.text != undefined" ng-bind-html="t.text">{{t.text}}</div>
        <div class="body" ng-if="t.highlights.text != undefined" ng-bind-html="t.highlights.text">{{t.highlights.text}}</div>
    </a>
    <time>{{t.fields.formatted_date_difference}} ago</time>
</section>
```

Comment: can use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` or a simple directive sets the html instead of using `ng-bind-html`

Comment: You can use ngIf for checking, may need to rework some of your markup though. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Are the tweets always one form or the other, or could they come in mixed?

Comment: @BenFelda thankfully only one or the other, but what would your suggestion have been if they come in mixed?

Comment: Thanks guys I think I got it :D `ng-if="t.text != undefined"` and `ng-if="t.highlights.text != undefined"` anyone want to post the answer?

Comment: If they came in mixed, I would suggest normalizing them to one structure before putting them in your controllers array so you wouldn't have to ugly up the view with the switch/if logic.

Comment: @LeonGaban  If you are going to use `ng-if` attributes, and if they are all the same structure, I wouldn't put the `ng-if` into the repeated `div`, but have two duplicate lists, and set a bool in the controller `isHighlights` that checks the first tweet.  `ng-if=isHighlighted` to the first list, and `!isHighlighted` to the second.  Fewer bindings, easier on memory.

Comment: @BenFelda so like `<section ng-if="t.text != undefined" ng-repeat="t in tweets">` ?

Comment: @LeonGaban no, just on the element that gets the text and don't need `!= undefined`

Comment: Could someone please post an example code block :o I'll update my post want I'm using now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Ben's suggestion, this shouldn't be in the view at all, it should be in the controller which is responsible for presenting the data model for rendering by the view.

```
$scope.tweets.forEach(function(t) {
    t._content = t.text || t.highlights.text || '';
});
```

Then render `t._content` in your view instead of `t.text` etc.

Comment: Oh hmmmm... yeah I think this is better

Comment: Hmm running into issues, I think I can get this working tho, if I do I'll check this.. will bbl

Comment: I had to put a check in to make sure `t.highlights.text` was not `undefined` but this is a cleaner way to do it, before the model data reaches the markup :)

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
$scope.isHighlights = false;

$scope.tweets = [];

$scope.getTweets = $http.get('url').then(function(data){
   //Get first tweet and set isHighlighted bool based on the property being defined
    $scope.isHighlighted = angular.isDefined(data[0].highlights);
    $scope.tweets = data;
});
```

View:

```
<div data-ng-if="isHighlights">
    <section data-ng-repeat="t in tweets">{{t.highlights.text}}</section>
</div>

<div data-ng-if="!isHighlights">
    <section data-ng-repeat="t in tweets">{{t.text}}</section>
</div>
```

This is lighter on memory with fewer bindings, and easier to read for anyone else checking out the code.  There are a million ways to skin this cat.  This way is assuming they will all be either one format or the other, and that there could be a lot of tweets on one screen.

Comment: Maintenance nightmare!

Comment: @randomsock  If the html inside the `section` gets anymore complex, then yes, I agree.